# What is the best way to produce 3d images of tangles and show them on the web so that they can be rotated by the viewer?

Tags: graphics3d, image3d, html

On my html5 website [on physics](https://www.motionmountain.net/research), I would like to add computer graphics of tangles, similar to the following photo, and I would like to allow users to rotate the image of a tangle and thus allow viewing the tangle from all sides.

Is this the right forum to ask?

If so, what is the best way to realize this, using Mathematica? (I also have KnotPlot as available tool.)

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

[image: simple tangle image]

Comment: Well, some time ago, I used embedded CDFs on a webpage. This should still work and it is also decently easy to implement from the developer side. But it requires the user to install the CDF player, which is probably something the user does not want fro security reasons. A more future-proof and lightweight way would be to place obj files with the tangles in the server and to use standard engines like WebGL or Unity to render it. (I am not an expert, though.)

Comment: What is the difference between WebGL and Unity?

Comment: What is the difference between Windows and Linux? ;) But seriously: I can't tell as I have not really used, yet. My impression is that Unity can do more (and is thus more complex; among browser games, Unity has become almost what Flash used to be a couple of years ago), but I guess WebGL is easier to learn. But I am really not an expert. Sorry.